# Codeigniter - Authentication Library or Custom Controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I'm wondering what is best in my case. I'm building a site using CodeIgniter with two main sections:

- the public part avalaible to everyone
- the private one only for registered users

In each page of the public area (one controller) I want to put a sign in form and a sign up link and if the users is logged in he has to be redirected to the private area or a link to it may be shown.

Now I have two choices:

1. A user controller is the first thing I thought of but in each page of the site I need to control if the user is logged and this is impossible or very bad since I'm using another Controller
2. So I started working on a library but I'm not sure how implement it (for example form validation should be achieved by the controller or by the library itself?, what about database connection since I haven't a model?)

What do you think is the best? Why? and how would you implement it?

(and yes I like reinventing the wheel and not using an existing library mainly because i want to learn how to do it)

Comment: How about just checking if the user is logged in in the constructor of `Users`?

Comment: but since i'm using a different controller to show site's pages i can't call a method of another controller or simply load it with the constructor without breaking the mvc model

Comment: CI is a bad framework to learn how to do that properly because it's static and therefore inflexible for extension and re-use - especially when it comes to controllers. Ideally I would decorate the controllers that need it with the access checks and define in routing which controllers need access checks. The application controller would then perform the access checks if a controller needs them.

Comment: i may extend the class ci_controller to do that...

Answer (score 0):

```
Super Controller
            =>assign user data,settings,configs etc
      |-----private controller extends super controller
            =>check user credentials
      |-----admin controller extends super controller
            =>check user && admin credentials
```

*Your super controller is your public controller as long as you only do assignments, no checking...*

*Anything you want public just extends super controller*

*Anything you want private extends private controller*

Comment: good idea, that way you can block sections/partial views or widgets    if(Modules::run('auth/_check_permissions', $user_id))

Answer (score -1):

Form validations and query jobs should be carried out with the controller itself. The library act like a tool no need to implement these things in them but as a need you can use queries in them to check some data but it's better to be worked in the controllers.

The idea for having a log flag is to:

1. When user is signed in, create a session for it to show the access.
2. Check every time the session for the private parts.